# How to Store the lastid that i get from the previous screen and fetch that id and click the id in the next tab

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

My Scenario:

In the First Form Creating Origin - I enter all the inputs like origin etc and save and on saving

the dynamic id gets generated

Second Screen Creating a Plan for the Origin -

1)In the Create Screen there is a Search option so i search with Origin which was created earlier and map it to the Plan Screen

2)After saving i navigate back to the Grid which has all the Rows added with the Origin information which is mapped to the Plan and also contains the dynamic ids  for each origini.

3)I have read the table and clicked on the row which contains the OriginName as "ORIGI" as seen below

```
List<WebElement> OriginName = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'mat-table')]//tr"));
int countrow = OriginName .size();

        for(WebElement originname:OriginName )
        {
            String text ="//td[contains(normalize-space(),'ORIGI')]";
            
            {
                
                WebElement id = originname.findElement(By.xpath(text));
                        
                id.click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

and it goes and navigates to the plan screen again and clicks on Send Proposal.

Issue:

The Actual Problem starts from here :

I then have to navigate to the Pending Confirmation section.

This section will have all the ids which has Proposal Sent but is not confirmed.

******The question here is how do i find the id for which the proposal is**

**accepted by me**  table.****

Can add more information ...Can someone please give inputs...

Comment: Can you add the code for generating/creating id? and where do you need to use/fetch it?

Comment: @NandanA : You might have not got his response.

Comment: sorry that was for another question which i posted this is not fixed still

Comment: @NandanA - i would need inputs

Comment: @NandanA - ID is Auto generated and need to use it in the planning screen

Comment: Add that code. How it is being generated?

Comment: should i post the screen shots pls confirm

Comment: Create screen i enter the above inputs and save

Comment: After saving when i navigate to tbe grid the id will get created for the particular origin

Comment: Then i navigate to the planning screen : and i take the newly created origin with the Origin name.Baiscally i read the table first  and check if the Origin name exist then go and click the Origin name :

Comment: please post in question

Comment: Looking into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hashmap` to store and get the data.

**Store the id in `hashmap`**

```
    public class CreateOrigin(){
    
    public static HashMap<String, String> createdValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    
    public void createOrigin(){
    
    //Code generate id
    
    createdValues.put("id", valueOfNewlyCreatedOrigin);
    
    }
   }
```

**Get the value from `hashmap`**

```
public class pendingConfirmationScreen(){

public String idOfOrigin = CreateOrigin.createdValues.get("id");

//Use idOfOrigin value in your code

}
```